# Passing data to socket from File using PrintStream and FileOutputStream

Tags: scala, sockets, file-io

I am trying to create a socket connection and then passing the values from the file to the socket as a stream.

I did managed to pass data to socket from the PrintStream,

```
    socketInput= "1234,112,1121"
    val ss = new ServerSocket(4141)
    val sock = ss.accept()
    val is = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream)
    val os =new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream))
    os.println(socketInput)
    os.flush()
    sock.close()
```

Now rather than providing the input to socket directly from Print stream I need to provide it from the csv file.
And while I was reading about the FileOutputStream it is used to write data to file.
How, Can we read from the file instead and pass to the socket.

Comment: so your question is how to read lines from a file?

Comment: @neuhaus so the question is how do I provide the input stream from the file itself rather than print stream.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to read content of a file and sending and receiving it through sockets, you can use these samples. First of all, You should run Server.java, after that please change path and name of file in Client.java and finally run client.

***Server.java***

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Server is ready:");
        int SERVER_PORT = 7005;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket conn = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT, 50);
            while (true) {
                conn = serverSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    if(line.indexOf("END") > -1) {
                        in.close();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

***Client.java***

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int SERVER_PORT = 7005;
        try {
            Socket conn = new Socket("localhost",SERVER_PORT);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/home/mohammadmehdi/development/eclipse/neonWorkSpace/javaTest/SocketTest/src/temp.txt"), "UTF-8"));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(line);
                out.flush();
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```